# Going through a constant list of tuples in C++

Tags: c++, list, stl, tuples

Sorry for stupid question. I'm trying to create and go through a constant list of pairs in C++, but couldn't find anything on Google so far. Ideally I get the first element and second element too in the for statement.

I so far have:

```
for (auto& tup : std::tuple<char*, char*> { {"", ""}, {"abc", "cba"}, {"abcd", "dcba"} }) {

}
```

In python it's really simple and I can just do (don't even need the square brackets):

```
for tup in [('', ''), ('abc', 'cba'), ('abcd', 'dcba')]:
    pass
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, a string literal is not allowed to be assigned to `char*`, so you should be using `const char*` anyway. `std::string_view` might be better.

With `std::tuple<char*, char*> { {"", ""}, {"abc", "cba"}, {"abcd", "dcba"} }`, you are trying to construct a *single* `std::tuple<char*, char*>` with a list of initializers for `std::tuple<char*, char*>`.

If you want to just go through a list of `std::tuple`s, you can list the type manually repetitively:

```
for (auto&& tup : { std::tuple<const char*, const char*>{"", ""},
                    std::tuple<const char*, const char*>{"abc", "cba"},
                    std::tuple<const char*, const char*>{"abcd", "dcba"} }) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Where, basically, a `std::initializer_list<std::tuple<char*, char*>>` is created, and is gone through. If you think this is too ugly, you can also specify the type only once:

```
for (auto&& x : std::initializer_list<std::tuple<const char*, const char*>>
    {
        {"a1", "a2"},
        {"b1", "b2"}
    }
) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

This should not be that complicated, just create an array of tuples.

And make sure that they are `const char*` not `char*`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int main() {

    std::pair<const char*, const char*> a[] =  { {"", ""}, {"abc", "cba"}, {"abcd", "dcba"} };

    for (auto& tup : a) {
        std::cout << std::get<0>(tup) << " " << std::get<1>(tup);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `std::initializer_list`:

```
for (auto& tup : std::initializer_list<std::tuple<const char*, const char*>> { {"", ""}, {"abc", "cba"}, {"abcd", "dcba"} })
{
    std::cout << std::get<0>(tup) << ", " << std::get<1>(tup) << std::endl;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/LuuTuH

That is pretty ugly to read though, I have to say.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a temporary array before:

```
std::tuple<const char*, const char*> tmp[]={ {"", ""}, {"abc", "cba"}, {"abcd", "dcba"} };

for (const auto& tup : tmp) {

}
```

Note that they must be `const char*` and not `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the list of tuples in more than one place in your code, create it separately:

```
constexpr std::tuple<std::string_view, std::string_view> the_list[] = {
    {"", ""}, {"abc", "cba"}, {"abcd", "dcba"}
};
```

Then using it will be simple:

```
for (auto& [one,two] : the_list) {
    std::cout << one << " , " << two << "\n";
}
```

If it's only going to be used in one loop, you can use an initializer list directly:

```
for (auto& [one,two] : std::initializer_list<std::tuple<std::string_view, std::string_view>>
    {
        {"", ""}, {"abc", "cba"}, {"abcd", "dcba"}
    }
) {
    std::cout << one << " , " << two << "\n";
}
```